# Does changing campaign names in AdWords mess up "Clicks to Sessions - rate" in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, universal-analytics, click-tracking

**Does Google Analytics import AdWords data from connected accounts for every querried report anew?**

The reason I'm asking is, that I get a **Clicks and Sessions Discrepancy** warning in Google Analytics and the AdWords report in Analytics states the following:

[image]

While search shows the usual discrepancy, all other campaigns either don't track sessions or clicks.

A coworker, who manages the campaigns in AdWords told me he renamed the campaigns as follows:

Timeline:

- Initially a  display campaign accidentally called *Remarketing* was created. This campaign was later renamed *Display 2*
- Also a new real *Remarketing* campaign got created afterwards (very recently)
- Finally, an display campaign original called *Display* got renamed to *Display 1* to be coherent with *Display 2*

My guess for part of the discrepancy is, that there are no clicks recorded for *Display* (without number) and *Remarketing*, because these campaigns were renamed in AdWords and therefore no longer exist. Hence, when the data from AdWords is querried the response returns 0. Since there is a new *Remarketing* campaign (with the exact same name as the old one) you would expect new sessions, but this campaign has just been installed.So, the 0 is still plausible.

Now, on the flip side, *Display 1* was originally named Display and inherited it clicks. These clicks can't be matched by sessions in Analytics as this campaing got paused after getting renamed.

**Finally, I can't explain why there are 0 sessions for the *Display 2* campaign.** While this campaign also inherited clicks from its former name *Remarketing*, it is active now and new clicks (and hence sessions) should come up, but there are still 0 sessions recorded in Analytics.

**Does anyone has an idea why that might be?**

Troubleshooting:

- Autotagging is activated
- Analytics code is implemented properly on all sites
- Loading time for the analytics code seems reasonable (see screenshot below)
- There are no redirectes coming from display ads

[image: There are two pixels, because Analytics is implemented twice right now (standard and via Tag Manager)]